# Select specific object from array of objects jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have stupid problem (probably). I need to select one of these objects to be able to use .empty() and .append(), for example, on them.

My problem is that if I select them like objectlist[1] it returns the html element not the jquery object.

This is my question, how can you select an object from an array of objects like one bellow and still be able to apply functions like .empty() and .append().

```
  r.fn.init(7) [div.alert-display, div.alert-display, div.alert-display, div.alert-display, div.alert-display, div.alert-display, div.alert-display, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
0: div.alert-display
1: div.alert-display
2: div.alert-display
3: div.alert-display
4: div.alert-display
5: div.alert-display
6: div.alert-display
length: 7
prevObject: r.fn.init [document]
__proto__: Object(0)
```

Comment: Maybe `$(objectlist[1])` ?

Comment: `objectlist.eq(0)`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: @Akshay it worked and it makes complete sense! Almost hit the keyboard with my head when I read that. Thanks a lot! :D  
The object list.eq(0) works as well and I think will be using this method because it seams a bit cleaner.

Comment: Great @GabrielRoman glad yo figured it out, and `.eq()` is the better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `objectlist.eq(1)`